# Why does my list of divs go outside its parent?

Tags: html, css

I've included a minimal representation of my code below that shows the problem I have. I want to contain everything inside the box and make the .content scrollable. Nothing I've tried seems to come close to solving the problem.

```css
.container {
  top: 13.5px;
  left: 16px;
  width: 377px;
  height: 140px;
  position: absolute;
  right: auto;
  bottom: auto;

  border: 1px solid red;
}

.content {
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.title {
  height: 30px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="title">
    <h2>Title</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div><span>Hello</span></div>
    <div><span>Hello</span></div>
    <div><span>Hello</span></div>
    <div><span>Hello</span></div>
    <div><span>Hello</span></div>
    <div><span>Hello</span></div>
    <div><span>Hello</span></div>
    <div><span>Hello</span></div>
    <div><span>Hello</span></div>
    <div><span>Hello</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set a height for your content. As such.

```
.content {
  height: 50%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use display:flex.

Here's the code:

```css
.container {
  top: 13.5px;
  left: 16px;
  width: 377px;
  height: 140px;
  position: absolute;
  right: auto;
  bottom: auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.content {
  overflow-y: auto;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.title {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="title">
    <h2>Title</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div><span>Hello</span></div>
    <div><span>Hello</span></div>
    <div><span>Hello</span></div>
    <div><span>Hello</span></div>
    <div><span>Hello</span></div>
    <div><span>Hello</span></div>
    <div><span>Hello</span></div>
    <div><span>Hello</span></div>
    <div><span>Hello</span></div>
    <div><span>Hello</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the title might vary in height

Comment: I did some changes to work with any height, i used `display:flex`.

Answer (score 0):

You just defined `overflow-y: auto` for `.content` .In order to make the `.content` scrollable you need to define height for your `<div class="content">`.

It will help you to avoid overflowing of contents outside the div.

```css
.container {
      top: 13.5px;
      left: 16px;
      width: 377px;
      height: auto;
      position: absolute;
      right: auto;
      bottom: auto;
    
      border: 1px solid red;
    }
    
    .content {
      overflow-y: auto;
       height: auto;
    }
    
    .title {
      height: 30px;
      border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="title">
    <h2>Title</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div><span>Hello</span></div>
    <div><span>Hello</span></div>
    <div><span>Hello</span></div>
    <div><span>Hello</span></div>
    <div><span>Hello</span></div>
    <div><span>Hello</span></div>
    <div><span>Hello</span></div>
    <div><span>Hello</span></div>
    <div><span>Hello</span></div>
    <div><span>Hello</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want the contents height to be dependent on the parents height.

Comment: It is possible if you make the `.container` and `.content` height as auto.It will make the auto according to the content. I've edited my answer, check it.Any further clarification let me know.